# Ruby prasing csv date to format invalid date(argumentError)

Tags: ruby, csv, date

I am parsing a csv file and i need to change the dob to match a certain format of `YYY-MM-DD` I keep getting this error of `parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)` 
it happens when it tries to parse this date of `"6/6/99"` How can i fix this so I don't get any errors for any of the dates I have?

list of all dates in csv, I am not sure if any of the other dates following the one above would error out as well.

```
"12/12/2010"
"1/1/1988"
"2/2/1966"
"6/6/99"
"1/4/88"
"4/4/1948"
"1/6/1988"
"1/7/1988"
"1/8/88"
"1/9/88"
"1988-02-12"
"1-11-88"
"1/12/88"
"1/13/88"
```

my code

```
require 'csv'
require 'time'
require 'date'

def parse_csv
  table = CSV.parse(File.read("input.csv", encoding: 'bom|utf-8' ), headers: true, col_sep: ",")
   formatted = table.map(&:to_h)
   formatted.each do |x|
   if x["dob"] =~ /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/
     p "correct"
   else
     parsed = Date.parse(x["dob"], "%Y-%m-%d")
     p parsed
   end
  end
end
parse_csv
```

Comment: The problem I see is when the date format doesn't match your expected format then the format could be anything: It could be valid but in an unexpected order, for example `"1/12/88"` could translate to `1988-12-01` or `1988-01-12`. Or it could just have an unexpected delimiter or could be totally invalid. How do you want to handle those cases? Are you fine with making a good guess with the risk being wrong? Or do you want just ignore those case without raising an error?

Comment: @spickermann i would probably want to raise an error just to cover my basis. As the csv just has a DOB header with dates listed as above. So, I am not sure how to proceed with that

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse):

> ```
> Date.parse
> ```
>
> Parses the given representation of date and time, and creates a date
> object.
>
> This method **does not** function as a validator. If the input string
> does not match valid formats strictly, you may get a cryptic result.
> Should consider to use `Date.strptime` instead of this method as
> possible.

Your current implementation doesn't really make sense; it's not doing what you think it is:

```
Date.parse('6/6/99', "%Y-%m-%d")
  #=> Date::Error: invalid date
```

This isn't saying "convert `"6/6/99"` into `"1999-06-06"`, it's saying "try to parse `"6/6/99"` into a `Date` object (and the second argument is essentially being *ignored*!).

If you're confident what format that date is *supposed* to be, then (as per the documentation referenced above!) you can use `Date.strptime` to try explicitly parsing it as this format. For example:

```
Date.strptime('6/6/99', "%m/%d/%y")
  #=> #<Date: 1999-06-06 ((2451336j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Or if you're not confident whether the first two values are supposed to represent month-day or day-month, then you'd need to handle this explicitly in the code and treat the error appropriately.

---

tl;dr:

- `Date.parse` is unreliable for arbitrary inputs; it only makes a "best guess" for the date format. And unsurprisingly here, it fails for at least one of the ambiguous formats you're throwing at it.
- `Date.strptime` is the correct way to parse each date, when you know which format you expect.